# Selecting data from Oracle XE with app made in IBM Integration Toolkit

Tags: oracle-xe, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying to create a new output message by selecting data from my Oracle XE schema. Application works, but data that is shown in output message has hexadecimal characters in between each letter. So my question is, what is happening there and why? Should I cast the whole sql statement into character? I've tried same thing with DB2 and works perfectly. I mean both DB2 and Integration Toolkit are products from IBM so I supose it has to be in perfect sync. Figured it's either something with db or maybe with ODBC driver or maybe even something third, wouldnt know.

Here is my ESQL code:

http://prnt.sc/o3wfk1

Here is my output message:

http://prnt.sc/o3wfp9

Here is data inside databse:

http://prnt.sc/o3wfsj

Here are results when running the app with DB2 databse:
http://prnt.sc/o3wk0d

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a direct SELECT without using PASSTHRU

SET Environment.Variables.data[]=SELECT I FROM tableName AS I

Comment: @ krishna movva I've tried with direct select, but it doesn't work, also your suggestion doesn't work